# AngularJS post data doesn't include for http body

Tags: angularjs

I'm sending a json object to a http post using Angular JS.

```
 var obj = {
      "username": email,
      "group": "team | " + designation
    };

    $http.post(`${API_URL}/member`, obj)
  .then((data) => {

    $mdToast.show(
      $mdToast.simple()
      .textContent('created successfully')
      .hideDelay(3000)
    )

    $route.reload()

  }, (error) => {

  })
```

From the server side I'm getting that username and group data to data.attributes like below.

```
request.body.data.attributes.username
```

I tried other ways as well. But it's same. I need to get these data to request.body.

```
request.body.username
```

Comment: No one to help?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly mention the full example i tried with the above and its working fine.

```js
(function () {'use strict';

angular.
  module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']).
  controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);

function HomeCtrl($mdToast, $scope, $http, $route) {
  $scope.showToast = function(content) {
    var obj = {
      "username": "as@aa.aa",
      "group": "team | " + "IT"
    };

 $http.post("https://httpbin.org/post", obj)
 .then((data) => {
    console.log(data.data.json);
  $mdToast.show(
   $mdToast.simple()
   .textContent('created successfully')
   .hideDelay(3000)
  )
  $route.reload()
 }, (error) => {

 }) 
  }
}

}());
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl" class="md-padding" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak>
   <md-content layout="column" layout-fill="" layout-padding="">
    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showToast('Test')">
      Show toast
    </md-button>
   </md-content>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```